# $.ajax still does not execute

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Here is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
<meta name="dcterms.created" content="Tue, 03 Feb 2015 08:06:46 GMT">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateLogIn()
{
var username  = $("#username").val();
var password  = $("#password").val();
var login  = $("#login").val();
//var remember  = $("#remember").val();
$.ajax({     
  url: 'validate.php',   //i never get to this file!                 
  type: 'POST',
  data: { 'username' : username , 'password' : password, 'login' : login} 
  }).done(function(response){  //Attach a succes handler
    alert(response); //this doesn execute
}); 
return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="crud.html" method="post" name="form_submit" onsubmit="return validateLogIn()">
   <input required placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
   <input required placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
   <label for="remember">Remember Me:</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="yes" id="remember" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <input type="submit" name="login" value="login" id="login"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

then validate.php

```
  <?php
 //i never get here i dont understand
  echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  echo $username = $_POST['username']; 
  echo$password = $_POST['password']; 
  if ($_POST['login']) //check if the submit button is pressed
  {
    $remember = $_POST['remember'];     
  ....../
```

I get this when I do `//localhost/php/validate.php`:

[image]

Comment: "//i never get to this file!" — How do you know?

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: `return false;` at the end of `validateLogIn()`

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: please see OP with pic added

Comment: so it does get to validate.php then........

Comment: What does " i get this when i do //localhost/php/validate.php" mean? Do you mean "When you go to that URL directly instead of using Ajax or submitting a form"? What does that have to do with the problem?

Comment: if your do a print_r($_POST); what do you get?

Comment: make sure both of your files are in the same directory otherwise your code works with me

Comment: and last but not the least you should execute `//localhost/php/{formpage not validate.php}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your 'data' property, in my opinion, you should remove the quotes.

Also to really debug and find out the answer, you should debug like this. Adding these other properties will help you determine what issues / errors you're getting.

```
$.ajax({     
    url: 'validate.php',   //i never get to this file!                 
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'xml', //YOu're missing this value!!!
    data: { username : username , password : password, login : login},
    beforeSend: function() {
        //This will execute regardless what happends before the AJAX is sent.
    },
    success: function(xml) {
        //Will execute if no errors are present while sending AJAX
    },
    error: function(xml) {
        //If any error happens while sending AJAX, this will be called.
    },
    complete: function(xHR, textStatus) {
        //This will execute regardless what happens.
    },
});
```

The "beforeSend" property will execute before anything is sent to the server to be validated.

The "success" Will only execute if there is no error in the dataType that is returned, or any error for that matter.

The "Error" will only execute if the returned data is not what dataType expected it to be.

The "complete" Will execute regardless what happens.

Comment: While property names in JavaScript object literals can be strings, they can also be identifiers, so switching from identifiers to strings won't make any difference … there is no JSON there, but if there was, quotes around property name would be *mandatory* and not forbidden.

Comment: @Quentin Very true. I've always had issues with making the "data" property with strings, so I never used them when making an AJAX call.

Answer (score 2):

I've checked your code works perfectly. So what's wrong?

If you access your `validate.php` directly, you don't send any data to it and hence `$_POST[]` contains nothing. You should visit your form page, type something in your form and click login and you should get an alert with response from your validate.php.

Via `AJAX` you send your request in the background and and if you send some data to your validate.php it will work otherwise it won't. I suggest you do all kind of error checking/handling.